# Sabre: REST Version of GetReservation?

Tags: sabre

We are calling the REST version of CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ in Sabre's test environment with no issues. However, there does not seem to be a REST version of GetReservation.

Is this true? Why would only some of the APIs be available in REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an early version of a new getBooking API that Sabre is in the process of development. Based on what attributes/elements of the Reservation you are need this could meet your needs.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/trip/orders/booking_management